# Cakephp 3 .htaccess File Configuration

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I've spent much time to find out this trouble, that my cakephp running on my localhost server, but when I move my cakephp to hosting server, cakephp just shows blank page, anyone have codes `.htaccess` in root folder, cakephp folder, and another that need for my cakephp running on server ?

for your information, my cakephp version is cakephp 3

I've tried with this code

1. in root `.htaccess`

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```
2. in my folder cakephp `.htaccess`

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteBase /my_app_name
     RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
     RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```
3. in my webroot folder

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
   </IfModule>
   ```

for many tutorial that I've read, they said we have set 3 `.htaccess` file, is there any wrong code in my `.htaccess` file so I cannot access my website?

[CASE CLOSED]

The solutions is just make sure your php already enable intl in your hosting / shared server

Comment: So you are trying to run your CakePHP application in a subfolder – not the `root`?

Comment: @Mary : Wherever, I just wanna make my application running on my hosting

Comment: Blank page ? Have you check the status code of your page because it can show blank page because of internal server error. Check the error log as well. In my case i have problem with my intl PHP extension.

Comment: status code 500, and sometime if I try to modify my .htaccess file, page will send error internal server

Comment: @KodeKite did you fix this issue?