# Configurating .htaccess file for my CakePHP 3 app located in a git repo subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Found a similar question
[Cakephp 3 .htaccess File Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735606/cakephp-3-htaccess-file-configuration)
but no answer there.

My GIT repo structure

```
ROOT
- .htaccess
- /htdocs (CakePHP 3 app)
- - .htaccess
- - /webroot
- - - .htaccess
```

**ROOT .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    htdocs/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) htdocs/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**htdocs .htaccess** (default)

```
# Uncomment the following to prevent the httpoxy vulnerability
# See: https://httpoxy.org/
#<IfModule mod_headers.c>
#    RequestHeader unset Proxy
#</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**htdocs/webroot .htaccess** (default)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

https://***.com/bestprice.com/ `(GIT repo location)`

I am actually redirected to htdocs (`htdocs` not displayed in url, just like I need), but get a Missing Controller error.

`Bestprice.comController could not be found.`

https://***.com/bestprice.com/htdocs/ *works fine*

I have tried many different ways and this is the best result I could achieve.

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Your Apache configuration should use `ROOT/htdocs/webroot` as the "DocumentRoot".

Comment: @GregSchmidt Sorry, I do not think I need to do anything with Apache config. .htaccess itself should be able to deal with it.

It works perfectly when I use url `https://***.com/bestprice.com/htdocs` or when CakePHP app is inside GIT repo root, not a subdirectory `htdocs`